# Making it easier to create a Form object in Play Framework with ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

**EDIT:** For those who wonder how I plan to solve it according to the accepted answer, see Nested Values [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms).

I'm using Play Framework with Scala and Reactive Mongo.

Currently I'm creating my case classes and forms like this:

```
case class Person(
  _id : Option[BSONObjectID],
  name: string,
  city: string)

object Person {
  val form: Form[Person] = Form {
    mapping(
      "_id" -> optional(of[String] verifying pattern(
      """[a-fA-F0-9]{24}""".r,
      "constraint.objectId",
      "error.objectId")),
      "name"-> text,
      "city"-> text)
    { (id,name, city) => Person(id.map(new BSONObjectID(_)), name, city) }
    { person =>Some(person._id.map(_.stringify), person.name, person.city)  }
  }
}
```

If I was using a simple type in the `_id` property, like `String`, I could do something simpler, like:

```
object Person {
  val form: Form[Person] = Form {
    mapping(
      "_id" -> text,
      "name"-> text,
      "city"-> text
      )(Person.apply)(Person.unapply)
  }
}
```

So I thought I could create my own apply method that would change the first parameter, using currying. I would define something like this:

```
def apply2(id: Option[String]) = {
  val bsonid = id.map(new BSONObjectID(_))
  (Person.apply _).curried(bsonid)
}
```

My theory, which implementation doesn't work, is that I would partially apply a `BSONObjectID` parameter to the `Person.apply` function, which value would come from the `apply2` parameter called `id`. It doesn't work.

I'm a lazy guy who doesn't want to type a bunch of things just because now I have a new situation which isn't supported by default... The currying is one of my bets, but any solution that would make it easier to create a Form is acceptable.

I just need a way to identify the object so I can delete or update it after, but the current way is kinda boring to type, and I think that the `_id` field created by MongoDB is perfect.

Is there a way I could make things easier or I just need to stop being lazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make things easier by creating 2 case classes. 
One to be used when data entry is in place

```
case class PersonData(name: String, city: String)
```

and another one to represent real Person in your model

```
case class Person(_id: BSONObjectID, name: String, city: String)
```

and in Person object create method:

```
def fromData(data: PersonData) = Person(
  id = new BSONObjectID(),
  name = data.name,
  city = data.city)
```

then your mapping From[PersonData] can be simpler, and You avoid Option[BSONObjectID] flying around your model.

Comment: Nice! That also solves the problem where my classes would be too coupled with MongoDB. 
I'll test it when I get home. 
What do you think about having something like `case class Person(_id: BSONObjectID, data: PersonData)`?

Comment: That is also good. From my experience, when your model grows I think it would be nice to keep editable data in *data* field eg. `Person(_id, data, events, connections, etc.)`. Also good pattern is to have special case class for id eg. `PersonId(value: BSONObjectID)`.

Comment: Cool. This way I can make it even easier by using Nested Values. I edited my answer. This way I need to declare only the part that grabs the Id from the form.

Thanks again!